# ¿Como inhabilito la función de recargar en chrome en el celular?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas tardes compañeros. Hoy me encuentro con un pequeño problemita. Quiero que en un formulario determinado, al momento que hagan deslizar(Celular, en chrome) para recargar el formulario no se pueda hacer. Es algo parecido como bloquear la tecla F5 o el botón de recargar del navegador(Computado, en chrome)... Espero haberme hecho entender... Los estaré leyendo!

Comment: No te entendí. ¿Puedes volver a escribir lo que quieres decir?

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta...

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer no se puede hacer, no hay manera de impedir que un usuario recargue cualquier página.

Comment: @PabloLozano tengo una respuesta por acá, a lo mejor sirva https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/244667/83304

Comment: @JheymanMejia Eso impide un gesto en particular en Chrome, pero Firefox por ejemplo no hace uso de ese gesto. Y nada te impide abrir el menú y darle a refrescar, o directamente dar en la barra de direcciones donde está la URL y luego pulsar Enter de nuevo

Comment: No he navegado en Firefox para móviles, me enfocaba en la pregunta del OP, deslizar en Chrome para móviles. Gracias por tus observaciones.

Comment: Con onbeforeunload cuando deslizas el dedo para actualizar la pagina desde un movil (uso chrome y ahi sale) te sale una alerta, ahi se puede cancelar la recarga o continuar, el mensaje no es personalizable, cada navegador tiene uno predefinido.

Answer (score 1):

Sigo sin entender muy bien tu pregunta pero hay una manera muy fácil de poner bloquear el F5 para recargar la página en jQuery.

Esto se debe al método de [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). Lo que hace el método es detener las acciones predeterminadas del elemento. Por ejemplo, un elemento `<a>` nos mandaría a una página. Bueno, con el método detendría esa acción predeterminada del elemento.

Entonces podríamos hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
function disableF5(e) { 
 if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) {
   e.preventDefault();
  }
};

$(document).on("keydown", disableF5);


$(window).on("focus", function(e) {
    $("html, body").css({ background: "#FFF", color: "#000" })
    .find("h1").html("F5 no trabajará aquí.");
})
.on("blur", function(e) {
    $("html, body").css({ background: "", color: "" })
    .find("h1").html("Aquí no prevengo el F5. Da clic para prevenirlo.");
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}
div { 
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Aquí no prevengo el F5. Da clic para prevenirlo.</h1>
</div>
```

**NOTA:** Esto solo desactivará la recarga de la página al dar clic en F5 en el teclado. Para ser sincero, no se como prevenir la recarga con el botón del navegador.

Comment: Hacía referencia el ejemplo de bloquear la tecla f5, en caso de computadores. Pero como puedo bloquear la funcion de refrescar una página en chrome en el celular (cuando tu deslizas el dedo sobre la pantalla del celular para refrescar)

Comment: En realidad no se puede bloquear o prevenir la recarga de una página deslizando de arriba para abajo en Chrome. Pero hay una manera de impedir que se borren los datos ingresados en cada inputs de un formulario: guardando en localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Esto se llama Pull Down to Refresh o Swipe Down to Refresh.

Puedes probar agregando esto en CSS:

```
html,
body {
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

o

```
html,
body {
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

Funciona para versiones nuevas de Chrome, Edge y Firefox, no en safari, para versiones viejas puedes agregar por JavaScript lo siguiente:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstartHandler, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener('touchmove', touchmoveHandler, {passive: false});
```

Este último no funciona en navegadores nuevos, pero si el de CSS, podrías dejar ambos, tanto CSS cono JavaScript.

Es verdad que nada impide que el usuario refresque si lo desea por menú, pero quizás tu idea sea solo bloquear el comportamiento que se puede generar por accidente al hacer scroll.

Espero sirva, quedo a las órdenes.