# Impedir que web se refresque al deslizar pantalla en navegador móvil

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quisiera saber si existe alguna posibilidad de evitar, que cuando esté navegando en mi aplicación móvil, el navegador recargue la página al deslizar la pantalla hacia abajo, en caso de Chrome para Android.

Cuando deslizo el dedo muy fuerte en Chrome móvil se recarga la página.

Me gustaria saber si se puede hacer alguna configuración durante la programación de la página para evitar que esto ocurra.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Agrega en tu CSS la siguiente propiedad a tu `body`

```
body {
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

Traducción de MDN:

La propiedad CSS `overscroll-behavior` establece lo que hace un navegador cuando alcanza el límite de un área de desplazamiento. Es una taquigrafía para `overscroll-behavior-x` y `overscroll-behavior-y`.

La propiedad toma tres valores posibles:

1. **auto** : predeterminado. El scroll que se origina en el elemento puede propagarse a elementos hijos.
2. **contain** - evita el encadenamiento de desplazamiento (*scroll chaining*). El comportamiento predeterminado de desbordamiento de desplazamiento se observa dentro del elemento en el que se establece este valor (por ejemplo, efectos de "rebote" o actualizaciones), pero no se produce un encadenamiento de desplazamiento a las áreas de desplazamiento vecinas, por ejemplo, los elementos subyacentes no se desplazarán.
3. **none** , igual que contain, pero no se produce el encadenamiento de desplazamiento a las áreas de desplazamiento vecinas, y se evita el comportamiento predeterminado de desbordamiento de desplazamiento.

---

```
/* Valores de atributo clave */
overscroll-behavior: auto; 
overscroll-behavior: contain;
overscroll-behavior: none;

/* Dos valores (X y Y respectivamente) */
overscroll-behavior: auto contain;

/* Valores Globales */
overflow: inherit;
overflow: initial;
overflow: unset;
```

De forma predeterminada, los navegadores móviles tienden a proporcionar un efecto de "rebote" o incluso una actualización de la página cuando se alcanza la parte superior o inferior de una página (u otra área de desplazamiento). También puede haber notado que cuando tiene un cuadro de diálogo con contenido de desplazamiento en la parte superior de una página de contenido de desplazamiento, una vez que se alcanza el límite de desplazamiento del cuadro de diálogo, la página subyacente comenzará a desplazarse, lo que se denomina encadenamiento de desplazamiento.

[image: Refresh de Twitter en Chrome para Android]

<sup>La acción nativa de actualización de Chrome de Android 
actualiza toda la página</sup>

En algunos casos estos comportamientos no son deseables. Se puede usar `overscroll-behavior` para deshacerse del encadenamiento de desplazamiento no deseado y el comportamiento del tipo "tirar para actualizar" inspirado en la aplicación de Facebook / Twitter del navegador.

> `overscroll-behaviour` también admite *shorthands* (propiedades
>   abreviadas) para `overscroll-behaviour-x` y `overscroll-behaviour-y`
>   si solo desea definir comportamientos para un determinado eje.

---

**Importante:** `overscroll-behavior` requiere Chrome 63+. Está en desarrollo o está siendo considerado por otros navegadores. Ver [chromestatus.com](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5734614437986304) para más información.

Fuentes:

*https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior*

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior*